# Horizontally and vertically center align DIV grid

Tags: css

I know this is a very old question and there are several approaches to this like using "flex" or fixed height etc.

But I found myself a new solution and need to understand if it's OK to use this way :

```
div.parent { 
display:table;
text-align:center;
}
div.child { 
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:middle;
width:33%;
}
```

This reason why I open this topic is to learn what are the drawbacks of using "display:table" for parent div. Because without it, multiple "child" divs collapsed due to unknown extra display:inline-block margin.

This method works like charm with pretty much all modern browsers yet I haven't come across before. So just need to make sure that it's alright to use.

Edit : I added width value to child

Demo :
https://jsfiddle.net/tcd8jkeb/

Comment: Can you post a fiddle of some kind?

Comment: This question is either too broad, **opinion based** or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: I added Jsfiddle and fixed CSS style. @Paulie_D you're right about it but there are many possible inside element types needed to understand if I'm missing something here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All `display:table` does is create a block level box "like a table". Without making the child elements `display:table-cell` or such, it doesn't do anything more than `display:block` does. Try it and see.

Comment: It's my bad. I forgot to add width value to the child. I also added demo.

Answer (score 0):

```css
div.parent { 
display:table;
text-align:center;
}
div.child { 
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
  <div class="child">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and </div>
  <div class="child">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: In what way does this answer the question?

Comment: The problem with table-cell is you can only create horizontal blocks. display-inline block create a grid, collapses to another row when width is wider than container. Also I agree with  @Rob

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
Do u need like this   

 <style>
    div.parent
    { 
    display:table;
    text-align:center;
    }
    div.child 
    { 
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:center;
    }

    </style>
    <html>
    <head>
    <body>
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="child">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
      <div class="child">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and </div>
      <div class="child">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five </div>


    </body>

</head>
```